# Get usable description for Apple Event

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, parsing, nsstring

So I have my code to get the current song that is playing by making a AppleScript object and using the returned value from AppleScript as the info that is sent to the user. Sadly it throws in a bunch of other junk that I need to get rid of.

Here is my code:

```
-(NSString *)getCurrentTrack {
    NSString *currentTrack = @"";
    NSAppleScript *getTrack = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"iTunes\" to get the name of the current track"];


    currentTrack = [getTrack executeAndReturnError:nil];

    return currentTrack;

    //tell application "iTunes" to get the name of the current track
}
```

The returned value of currentTrack is:

```
<NSAppleEventDescriptor: 'utxt'("track name here")>
```

So I need to get rid of `<NSAppleEventDescriptor: 'utxt'("
and the ")> at the end`

Answer (score 1):

[getTrack executeAndReturnError:nil] return  a NSAppleEventDescriptor

To get a NSString from a NSAppleEventDescriptor :

```
NSAppleEventDescriptor *resultDescriptor = [getTrack executeAndReturnError:nil];
return [resultDescriptor stringValue];
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you're using garbage collection... if not notice that you used alloc to create the NSAppleScript. As such you would need a release statement for getTrack.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works:

```
-(NSString *)getCurrentTrack {
    NSString *currentTrack = @"";
    NSAppleScript *getTrack = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"iTunes\" to get the name of the current track"];


    currentTrack = [getTrack executeAndReturnError:nil];

    currentTrack = [currentTrack stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"'"];
    NSArray *left = [currentTrack componentsSeparatedByString:@"('"];
    NSString *text2 = [left objectAtIndex:1];
    NSArray *right = [text2 componentsSeparatedByString:@"')"];

    return [right objectAtIndex:0];


    //tell application "iTunes" to get the name of the current track
}
```

It should return `track name here` using the `<NSAppleEventDescriptor: 'utxt'("track name here")>` example you gave me, however I escaped the `"` manually, as I created a fake response like so: `currentTrack = @"<NSAppleEventDescriptor: 'utxt'(\"track name here\")>";`

Please tell me if it worked, -Joseph Rautenbach (you know me lol)